# Drupal: Varnish and cookies

Tags: drupal, cookies, varnish

I'm using drupal with varnish, and I need to teach it about cookies. Anyone know where to start? Google does me no favors, thank you all in advance.

http://drupal.org/node/700022

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you try Pressflow.
Drupal has the bad habit of sending Cookies to all users (even anonymous users).
Pressflow is very cache-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a nice guide here:
http://varnish-cache.org/wiki/VarnishAndDrupal

I don't know if this is still of interest to you, 4 months on now. You'll need to use Drupal 7 or later.